# Ask unbiased estimator of $\sigma ^2$ in normal distribution when either $\mu$ known or $\mu$ unknown？

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

If $\mu$ is unknown, then $\frac{1}{n-1}  \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline X)^2$ is the unbiased estimator of $\sigma ^2$.

However, if $\mu$ is known, then $\frac{1}{n}  \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu)^2$ is the unbiased estimator of $\sigma ^2$.

I am very confused. From introductory statistics class, I know that given any random population, $E(S^2)$ is always equal to $\sigma ^2$. Hence, for a normal distribution, I think the sample variance = $\frac{1}{n-1}  \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline X)^2$ should always be unbiased.

Comment: Hint: calculate the expected value of both estimators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course if the mean is a known value it is self evident that it is better to use it instead of using an estimation of the mean...to understand if the "natural" estimator for $\sigma^2$ is biased / unbiased it is enough to calculate its expectation

$$\frac{1}{n}E(\Sigma_iX_i^2-2\mu\Sigma_iX_i+n\mu^2)=E(X^2)-2\mu^2+\mu^2=\sigma^2+\mu^2-2\mu^2+\mu^2=\sigma^2$$

---

Furthermore observe that you are in a Gaussian model, thus it is important to realize that

$$\frac{\Sigma_i(X_i-\overline{X}_n)^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi_{(n-1)}^2$$

while

$$\frac{\Sigma_i(X_i-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi_{(n)}^2$$

Comment: Thank you for your supplement. I learn it. But what is the sample variance when $\mu$ is known? I know sample variance is $\frac{1}{n-1} \Sigma_i(X_i-\overline{X}_n)^2$ when both parameter $\mu , \sigma^2$ are unknown. But what is the sample variance when $\mu$ is known?

Answer (score 2):

The intuition is that if you have to estimate $\mu$ then $\overline{X}$ will be the minimizer of

$$f(m) = \sum_{i = 1}^n (X_i - m)^2.$$

To see this, set the derivative equal to $0$:

$$f'(m) = \sum_{i = 1}^n 2(X_i - m) = 0 \iff \left(\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i\right) - nm = 0.$$

But that means that if $\mu$ is the true mean

$$ \sum_{i = 1}^n (X_i - \overline{X})^2 \le \sum_{i = 1}^n (X_i - \mu)^2.$$

And so there is some bias introduced when we want to estimate $\sigma^2$, because $\sum_{i = 1}^n (X_i - \overline{X})^2$ is too small.

Well, it turns out that $\sum_{i = 1}^n (X_i - \overline{X})^2$ is too small by exactly a factor of $\frac{n - 1}{n}$.

In summary,

$$\mathbf{E}\left[ \frac{1}{n - 1} \sum_{i = 1}^n (X_i - \overline{X})^2 \right] = \mathbf{E}\left[ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n (X_i - \mu)^2 \right] = \sigma^2.$$

Thus both
$$ \frac{1}{n - 1} \sum_{i = 1}^n (X_i - \overline{X})^2 \text{ and } \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n (X_i - \mu)^2$$

are unbiased estimators of $\sigma^2$. The second estimator is "better" in the sense that it's variance from $\sigma^2$ is smaller, but the catch is that one needs to know the true mean in order to use it.

Comment: Thanks. But what the sample variance in 2 cases? ($\mu$ known or unknown)

Comment: @Yichuan You have two unbiased estimators, $s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum (X_i - \overline{X})^2$ and $\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac1n \sum (X_i - \mu)^2$. If you don't know $\mu$ then obviously you can't use $\hat{\sigma}^2$, and you have to use $s^2$ instead. If you do know $\mu$ then you should use $\hat{\sigma}^2$ because $\operatorname{Var}(\sigma^2 - \hat{\sigma}^2) < \operatorname{Var}(\sigma^2 - s^2)$ so it's "closer" to the true value of $\sigma^2$.